# HTTP Basic Auth in RESTful API with PHP

Tags: php, api, rest, apache2, basic-authentication

I'm using Fat Free Framework for a small RESTful API. I want the user to authenticate for each requests with HTTP Basic Auth like this:

http://user:sha1(pass)@server.org/[...]

My problem is that I can't get these credentials.
Our client (Browser: AJAX Request with jQuery) sends them 100%, but I cant find anything in $_SERVER in PHP.

It looks like Apache doesn't forward user + pass to PHP.

Does anyone know why not? And how I can realize HTTP Basic Auth with PHP?

best regards

Comment: http://fatfreeframework.com/auth#basic

Comment: If you're only `sha1`-hashing your users' passwords, you should read this article: http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to find the username and password in `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']` and `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']`.

There's a great article on php.net on this topic: http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php

Comment: Exactly this is what it should be like - but its not working!
Both are empty.....

Comment: @Tobi It looks like there are some hints in the comments on the article I linked to. Try searching for "apache" on that page.